# Change listview text Android

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-sqlite

I have a SQLite database that is converted into a listview and everything is working fine. But i am facing a problem now:

I have a column named stage in my database. Stage will contain one of these integers: 0, 1 or 2. In the layout file of the listview items i have a textview called status, and the value of stage is printed into this textview. But i don't want 0, 1 or 2 printed in the textview, i want to replace the integer with a word.

So for example if the value of stage is 0, i want the content of status to be "hello". And if the value of stage is 1, i want the content of status to be "goodmorning". I have tried multiple things but i don't get it working.

**The code of the listview:**

```
private DBManager dbManager;

private ListView listView;

private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

final String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseHelper._ID,
        DatabaseHelper.IDEA, DatabaseHelper.DESC, DatabaseHelper.STAGE};

final int[] to = new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.idea, R.id.desc, R.id.status };

dbManager = new DBManager(this);
dbManager.open();
Cursor cursor = dbManager.fetch();

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_view_record, cursor, from, to, 0);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I hope somebody can help me, thanks in advance :).

Comment: can you add screen shot how do you want?

Comment: You need to override the getView of your adapter if you want to customize the rendering. Or you need to add a switch clause in your sql query to replace the value in the select.

Comment: `I have a SQLite database that is converted into a listview` **NO**. You are displaying som og f your database contents into a ListView. No "conversion" happens. What I would do here is adding another table with the values for 0, 1 and 2 (or even more). And JOIN the tables so that you display the column(s) that you want from the first table + the corresponding status descriptions from the other table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a custom adapter rather than using SimpleCursorAdapter and then change/convert the value in the **getView** or **bindView** method within the adapter.

Alternately you could change/convert the values via the query that returns the cursor. Along the lines of :-

```
SELECT col1, col2,  (CASE WHEN colx = 0 THEN 'Hello' ELSE 'GoodMorning' END) AS mynewcolum FROM TABLE;
```

Where col1, col2 and colx are existing columns and colx is the column that is to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Take

```
int i;
```

Then check

```
if (i==0) {
    textview.setTe xt("hello");
} else if (i==1) {
    textview.setText("good morning");
}
```